# Windows Form Calculator - Numpad Keys For Input

Tags: c#, windows, numbers

I am currently in the middle of learning c# for my job, I have been trying some starter projects and i decided to make a calculator, I have all of the functions of a simple calculator working, however i can not get the numpad keys to work with a keypress event or a keydown event, I am wondering if someone can help me in some detail, i am wanting to sett all of the numpad keys to the corrspondings ones on the calculator, here is the code i have tried for the keypress event and i have also tried this with numpad lock on and off.

```
 private void n1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar = '1')
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            n1.PerformClick();

        }

    }
```

Just a quick edit, i have tried to follow MSDN example and include the following

private void n1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {

```
        if (e.KeyCode < Keys.D0 || e.KeyCode > Keys.D9)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode < Keys.NumPad0 || e.KeyCode > Keys.NumPad9)
            {
                nonNumberEntered = true;
            }
        }
```

And still no success

Comment: If reading the documentation is out of the question, use the F9 key to put a breakpoint on the `if` line in your code. Then try pressing a number-pad digit key and use the watch window to find out what `e.KeyChar` is equal to in that case. You can take a look at the other properties of `e` as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculator keypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031080/calculator-keypress)

Comment: I have checked & with NumLock on - pressing the 1 key does result in getting a KeyPress event with the value of e.KeyChar equal to '1'.

Comment: Looking at your code I see the method is n1_KeyPress - do you have multiple buttons each with a key press event attached n2_, n3_ ...? The KeyPress event will only happen for the button that has focus.

Comment: So i did decide to re-write said code in a different form, and i still have no such luck, private void n1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.NumPad0 || e.KeyCode == Keys.D0)
        }
    }

Answer (score 1):

Refer to MSDN [Key Enum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys.aspx) page for reference.

e.g. `Keys.NumPad0` is on keypad, `Keys.D0` is the number key. So you want to do something like this

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.NumPad0 || e.KeyCode == Keys.D0)
```

And also you probably want to map the operators, e.g. `Keys.Add` for your add.

Answer (score 0):

Check what the equals operator should be.

```
if (e.KeyChar == '1')
```

(You won't be the last person to fall down that particular hole, trust me....)

Comment: I don't think this is the issue - as it stands the code will not compile reporting "cannot implicitly convert char to bool" - in C# it is only possibly to accidentally use an assignment operator in place of a Boolean expression if the assignment is a Boolean or there is an implicit conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a comparison instead of assigning.

Comment: See my comment above - the code will not compile with that assignment.